# Autofac register generic instance with concrete type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I want to register a interface to a specific implementation. The interface and the class both are generic instances, here it goes:

**This is the container registration:**

```
builder.RegisterType<ParsedStatement>()
       .As<IParsedStatement>()
       .InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<NpoiParser<ParsedStatement>>()
       .As<IParser<IParsedStatement>>()
       .InstancePerDependency();
```

**The interface for IParser:**

```
 public interface IParser<T> where T : class
```

**The implementation of NpoiParser**

```
 public class NpoiParser<T> : BaseParser<T>, IParser<T> where T : class
```

ParsedStatement class already implements the interface IParsedStatement.
Although when i start the application I get this error from the  the build of the autofac container

> System.ArgumentException: 'The type `` RF.Infrastructure.Parser.NpoiParser`1[RF.Domain.ValueObjects.ParsedStatement] `` is not assignable to service `` RF.Domain.Interfaces.Parser.IParser`1[[RF.Domain.Interfaces.ValueObjects.IParsedStatement, RF.Domain.Interfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] ``.'

I could use a generic approach like this:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(NpoiParser<>))
       .As(typeof(IParser<>))
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

It works but doesn't allow me to use `IParser<ParsedStatement>` on the services since the NpoiParser class needs a concrete class since it uses a library and in that library only classes are permitted otherwise returns me the error "Cannot create an instance of an interface.".

The stack trace for the error when using generic is the following one:

```
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& hasNoDefaultCtor)    
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtorSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean fillCache)    
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, Boolean wrapExceptions)   
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic, Boolean wrapExceptions)    
at Npoi.Mapper.Mapper.<Take>d__66`1.MoveNext()    
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)   
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    
at RF.Infrastructure.Parser.NpoiParser`1.ParseFile(Stream fileToParse,  ITemplateDefinition info) in D:\Trabalho\RoyaltyFlush\royaltyflush.backend\RF.Infrastructure.Parser\NpoiParser.cs:line 52
at RF.Infrastructure.Parser.NpoiParser`1.ConvertStreamFileToObjectList(Stream fileToParse, ITemplateDefinition info) in D:\Trabalho\RoyaltyFlush\royaltyflush.backend\RF.Infrastructure.Parser\NpoiParser.cs:line 35
```

Any ideas on how i can register it on AutoFac with a specific class type?

Comment: "doesn't allow me to use IParser<ParsedStatement>" it should work or I don't understand something. Could you edit your post with the error message when you use `RegisterGeneric`

Comment: WHen I use generic it says  "Cannot create an instance of an interface".

Comment: Where do you have this error message ? do you have any stack trace ? Instead of `.As(typeof(IParser<>))` does `.As(typeof(NpoiParser<>))` fix the problem ?

Comment: But I need the IParser interface so I can use it on other services and could mock it to be able to test.
The error is thrown on the NpoiParser implementation. 
It's thrown since I'm using a library called NpoiMapper that takes a generic parameter, and that parameter it's a class, no interface allowed.

Comment: it's still unclear to me. Could you edit the post and add the stack trace of the exception and the expected result ?

Comment: sure, it's already updated with the stack trace

Comment: Still unclear. What do you want to inject ? where ? could you share the constructor of the class where the problem happens and how you want it to be called using pure C# ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Registering `NpoiParser<ParsedStatement>` as `IParser<IParsedStatement>` is like registering *apple* as *orange*.

`NpoiParser<ParsedStatement>` does not implement `IParser<IParsedStatement>`, it only implements `IParser<ParsedStatement>`.

```
// Compile error
IParser<IParsedStatement> obj = new NpoiParser<ParsedStatement>();
```

There are two ways you could fix this:

1. Inject `IParser<ParsedStatement>` instead of `IParser<IParsedStatement>`.
2. Change `IParser<T>` to [covariant generic interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier) by using `out` keyword. So change `IParser<T>` to `IParser<out T>`. But that requires the interface is indeed an covariant interface.